# How to access controller from route in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

Is there any foolproof way to access controller from a route?

```
<a href="#" class="btn" {{action "someAction" user}}>add</a>

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  events:
    someAction: (user) ->
      console.log 'give me name from currentUser controller'
```

The someAction is very general and I think that ApplicationRoute is the best place for it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the method `controllerFor` should be available in this event:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  events:
    someAction: (user) ->
      console.log this.controllerFor("currentUser").get("name")
```

**Update** in response to the questions in the comments:

*It all depends on what you want to do.* Worrying about DRY on such a basic method, does not make much sense imho.

In your kudos left case I would do this:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  events:
    someAction: (user) ->
      this.controllerFor("currentUser").decrementKudos();
      // implement the decrementKudos in your controller
```

But I guess storing this one controller should also work, if this is too much code for you:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  currentUserCon : this.controllerFor("currentUser")
  events:
    someAction: (user) ->
      this.currentUserCon.decrementKudos();
      // implement the decrementKudos in your controller
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to get a reference to that property, e.g can I store it in a variable so that I can operate on it?
`name = this.controllerFor('currentUser').get 'name'`
`return "hello, #{name}`
is it possible? Accessing controllers in such a way many times is not DRY :)

Comment: For example this would be an overkill:
`this.controllerFor('currentUser').set 'kudosLeft', this.controllerFor('currentUser').get 'kudosLeft' - 1`
:)

Comment: @WojtekRyrych Also, this: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/working_with_objects/incrementing_or_decrementing_a_property/

Comment: I'm not sure when this happened, but in Ember 1.12.0, `controllerFor` is deprecated.

Comment: You can inject it with Ember.inject.controller() or from a route there is a this.controller property to use,

Answer (score 10):

In the newer version of ember you can access current route's controller in route as below

**Ember version 2.5**

```
currentUserCon : this.controller
```

if you want to access other routes controller then use `controllerFor` method.

```
this.controllerFor('path to controller'); //put path to controller as parameter.
```

Comment: I've found (at least in my Ember 2.14 app) that `this.controller` is `undefined` at least through the `activate()` route hook, but `controllerFor('current.route.name')` will return the controller.

Comment: Like @TomWayson I have found that this doesn't work in Ember 2.13 . The doco suggests it's there but if fails when you try to use it. . I was able to use `this.controllerFor` successfully.